ESP32 (C++) use both AccelStepper.runSpeed() and Audio.loop() (blocking)
In my ESP32 C++ project I use Audio.h and AccelStepper.h.
Unfortunatelly the stepper is not working whenever audio is active. Seems like the Audio.loop() blocks too long.
Example code:
#include <AccelStepper.h>
#include <Audio.h>

#define IN1 25
#define IN2 26
#define IN3 27
#define IN4 14

#define stepsPerRevolution  2048/60

AccelStepper motors[1] = {AccelStepper(AccelStepper::FULL4WIRE, IN1, IN3, IN2, IN4)};
Audio audio;

void setup()
{

  // Some stuff to build up Wifi connection was removed here. Wifi is working.

  motors[0].setMaxSpeed(stepsPerRevolution * 10); // 10 rpm
  motors[0].setSpeed(stepsPerRevolution * 10);

  audioController.connecttohost("https://stream.antenne.de/antenne/stream/mp3");

  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
  motors[0].runSpeed();
  audio.loop();
}

Whenever I comment out audio.loop(), the stepper is moving correctly. Whenever I use audio.loop(), the stepper moves pretty slow and gets warm.
Hoping for help. Thanks

Well, both calls in loop() are alternating between running and blocked (waiting for the other function to finish).
The reasonable thing to do is creating separate tasks for them, as Bilal suggested. Since you're already coding C++ on Arduino, I'll skip the underlying FreeRTOS tasks and go straight to STL threads for brevity and clarity:
... all other code as is ...
#include <thread>
#include <assert.h>
#include "esp_pthread.h"

void setup() {
  motors[0].setMaxSpeed(stepsPerRevolution * 10); // 10 rpm
  motors[0].setSpeed(stepsPerRevolution * 10);
  audioController.connecttohost("https://stream.antenne.de/antenne/stream/mp3");
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Retrieve current thread configuration
  esp_pthread_cfg_t threadConf;
  auto result = esp_pthread_get_cfg(&threadConf);
  assert(ESP_OK == result);
  // Configure a rather big default stack size for new threads
  threadConf.stack_size = 16*1024;
  result = esp_pthread_set_cfg(&threadConf);
  assert(ESP_OK == result);
  // Launch a new task, the lambda with audio loop is executed there
  std::thread audioThread([](){ while (true) audio.loop(); });
  audioThread.detach();
}

void loop() {
  // Arduino's loop() runs as usual
  motors[0].runSpeed();
}

For details on how FreeRTOS tasks work, read their excellent tutorial/book. For details on C++ STL threads, read their reference or google for a tutorial (haven't encountered a really good one myself, so won't link any).
-- edit --
As an attempt to fix the error you've encountered I added a bit of extra code to increase the stack size of newly created threads to 16KiB - choose the value that works for you.

Those changes give me the following error message:
Guru Meditation Error: Core  1 panic'ed (Unhandled debug exception). Debug exception reason: Stack canary watchpoint triggered (pthread)
I think it's a stack overflow? How can I fix it?

Well, the new thread's stack seems to be to small to fit whatever audio.loop() is doing. I added some code to increase the stack size immediately before creating the thread. Feel free to experiment with the stack size (16KiB is probably too much, maybe too little).

Thats Because the audio.loop() plays the loaded files whenever called and then moves on.
You may need to create separate tasks and add audio.loop() and stepper code in separate tasks.
